# How can I put dimension relative to component center in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium

I have an Altium Designer PCB with some tactile switches.

In the same project a have a "Dimensions" layer where I specify important dimensions to be passed to the PCB manufacturer and the case design team in our company.

Placing dimensions of the board outline is very easy to me, but I'm unable to find a way to place a dimension relative to the center of an object (switch or IC for example).

I tried to open the component properties and add some axes to the component in the hope they would be an 'snap object' to the dimension tool, but the axes does not show in the GUI.

Does anyone knows how to place a dimension relative to component center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out.

All you have to do is to enable "Component Reference Point" in view configurations dialog:[image]

Then all components will have a Reference Point. Now the dimension tool have the snap point to be used:
[image]

Comment: Hi @RHaguiuda, Could you give me a hint as to where I might find this in a later version of Altium?

Comment: @bmalbusca I was able to get the same functionality on version 22, by opening the properties panel (you need to make sure that you have no objects selected - the properties panel will show the properties for the board object on the top), and on the "Objects for snapping" mark the option "Footprint origins".